Drill perpendicular hole through thick lumber using handheld drill
When using a cordless drill to make 1/2" holes in 4x4 or 6x6 lumber:
Despite taking my time, I find the holes I drill aren't perpendicular to the board. What can be done to drill better holes?
Off-grid location; no access to electricity or power tools like a drill press. Various applications.

Not a product recommendation, but I've seen drill guides which attach to your drill bit and project two lasers. When the circles are round and concentric, you know you're good. There are various other methods which generally involve making a guide to pass the bit through

Get a manual drill stand - did that when doing 8x8 for my son's deck, also made a wood frame for it to clamp it to the 8x8 beams.

drill holes in scrap wood block until you get a vertical hole ... then use the block as a drill guide

Most of us cannot tell a perfect 90 from a 80/85 by eye alone.  One reason you can spend days looking at drill guides to help.  If the holes need to be perfectly perpendicular, then a guide is the best choice.  Most might need a square to set up the first time.

I would mention practicing on a scrap pieces of wood and note an failures/error before doing the real piece.

Somewhere I once saw a small drill guide that would attach to a drill.  It kind of looked to me like a large T-nut.  Unlike the larger guides in the answers below, it only helped with perpendicular drilling. It seemed like such a useful tool, but I've never seen or heard of it since.


Use a visual guide of some sort. This can be as simple as a carpenter's square to which you'll align your bit by eye. Be sure to check two axes at right angles.

Use an actual guide. This doesn't need to be a fancy tool. If you can create a bore you know to be square with the board in something durable like hardwood, use it to start the rest of your holes. A scrap of two-by is enough for a half inch bit.

Drill halfway from each side. This halves and averages the error. Once the holes are connected, run the bit all the way through, urging it in the correct direction to emerge at the opposing bore face. Starting with a smaller bit and finishing with the final size can reduce interior cavitation.

Practice. Make mental notes of your faulty tendencies. Are you tilting the drill as you press? Are you favoring your dominant eye when you judge vertical? Practice and learn.



Using the "halfway" method, with a smaller diameter bit than the final desired size will give you additional guidance as well.

A "hack" from years ago was to use a Compact Disc (CD).
Place the CD as if you need to drill the hole through the middle of the disk, with the shiny side outward.  For a vertical surface, that may require temporary tape.
Hold up your drill and bit ready to start drilling, but take a moment first to ensure the reflection of the bit in the CD's shiny side is a straight line to the bit you can see directly.
Source: https://www.woodmagazine.com/drills/fine-tune-drill-bit-angle-using-a-cd

Coincidentally the algorithm just turned up:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=E-glhRXBMa4&t=613

I don't get the hack but maybe I am overthinking.    If the hole is smaller than the middle of the cd then how does it help?    If the hole is bigger than the cd how does it help?     I think when I first saw this I thought you were drilling through the cd itself.

@DMoore the CD hole size would limit the hole diameter that can be drilled, but with a mandated size of 15mm its big enough for OP's 1/2" or any reasonable pilot drill.   The CD helps with the reflection - your eye is very good at spotting if something is in-line or not.   If the drill bit and its reflection are not direct continuations of each other, then the drill is crooked.  Check again from above or below to correct in the Y direction.    Try it and see for yourself how it works.

One aspect that isn't mentioned is that you'd need to check on two different axes. If the drill is leaning directly toward the eye, for example, it'll still appear as a straight line.

There is a tool out there called a drill guide that might help.



In an off-grid application, they may be using a hand drill which requires both hands. Both drill guides shown here appear to have 4 holes in the base you could use to hold it in place if you're unable to hold the handle at the same time.

That is a little bit overkill unless you are manufacturing furniture.

@DMoore, and get in the way of certiain locations... but you want, want a perpendicular whole, and not an almost perpendicular whole.. This is how to do it.

No I agree.   It just seems like the guy is building a deck and wants to know a way to drill holes better with his cordless drill.    It is good that the tool is shown but realistically 99% of homeowners don't require this nor would they have room for it.   I drill way way way more holes than the average homeowner and I haven't even thought about buying one for a split second.

Maybe could clamp it down with c clamps to free up hands? :)

@DMoore I checked some hardware stores in my country (which has significantly higher average prices than the US) and you can buy simple drill guides (not as complex as those) for around 10$. Even if you only use it for one single project, seems an easy decision to get it.

@YanickSalzmann the block-style drill guides are cheap ($10-$20), the ones above run from $40-$60


Mark the spot on both sides exactly.
lay lumber down with one of the marks facing up.
drill straight down into the lumber half of its depth - usually with drilling straight down you can stay perpendicular much easier
flip it over and do the same to the other side
flip it over and go all the way through.   You may need to edge drill but should not be using much force.


Further suggestions:

drill a hole in a piece of mirrored plastic, put that on the workpiece and align the drill so it is straight with its reflection, then it will be perpendicular to the workpiece.
use a laser level with vertical beam pointing at the bit to give you a reference in one axis; usually I find that I'm good enough left/right so use the laser for forward/backward.


If you have access to something (a drill press for example) that can drill a perpendicular hole, take a block of wood and drill one or more holes with the intended drill bit. When you are in the field, use that block of wood as a guide by clamping it to where you want to drill.
It is easy to see that the thicker the guide block, the more accurate the angle is likely to be. You would choose the thickness based on the drill bit length and lumber thickness, etc. Drill more than one hole because you can move to another when one starts to get worn out and becomes sloppy.

.. and If there's no drill-press around, just buy the guide block.

Or get a selection of ideas here

I used one of the fancy guides like others have shown to drill straight throug the center of a 24" beam (with lots of bit changes, since the guide only has about 8" of depth). This one, for anybody who cares (very high quality): https://www.woodpeck.com/auto-line-drill-guide.html
But there are much cheaper and simpler ones for drilling things like 4x4s: https://www.amazon.com/dp/B0061FY004
BTW: love, love, love the answers with the CDs and other reflective surfaces!

Super simple answer,
If you need level holes in vertical lumber that is already attached, then simply hot glue a level vial on to your drill so that it is level when the drill is at level. such as this one:


If your drilling holes into Lumber on the ground or on a stand then you can hot glue a bullseye level to the back of your drill:


My first drill had both style levels on it, but I haven't seen them built in since then.

Here is how I usually do it.

Find a piece of scrap wood (2x4 is good).  Drill a perpendicular hole through it (the same size as you intend to drill through the larger wood).  I use a drill press, but use whatever method you have.

Clamp (or nail) the scrap to the large piece of wood.

Use the wood as a guide to drill through the larger piece.



This is definitely not for everyone, but what I would consider doing is to sketch up a drill guide in a CAD program and 3D print it. If hundreds of holes were necessary, then try to find a metal tube with a 0.5" ID and fit that to the print, otherwise just print a few of them. It could be designed to locate on the so-called 6" lumber (about 5.5", I think) with some side rails or whatever.
But a block of scrap wood with a drill press hole through it would be good too, and faster to make.

Why CAD and 3-D print something that can be purchased relatively inexpensively at higher precision and durability?

@Reid Yes, to get it now (or right after dinner) at negligible cost in time or materials. It would be more than 'good enough'. I've done that with a number of jigs and fixtures and it has generally worked out quite well.  In my case, I have metalworking capability (drill, mill, engine lathe, grinders, TIG welder, shear etc.), but 3D printing is so easy and fast.
